# React Router does not rerender component after going to different link

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm currently trying to use react router to redirect my website to another page.

However, whenever I visit the endpoint defined in express, instead of rerendering the page, all I get is the test string that I got from res.send() in express.

However, I want to be able to re-render the components as if it were another page instead of just receiving some text from the server.

```
render(
    <Router history = {hashHistory}>
        <Route path = "/" component = {Main}/>
        <Route path = "/posts" component = {PostDetail} />
    </Router>
,document.getElementById('app'))
```

I use this as a way to load different components depending on the path.

Here is my Main component.

```
class Main extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this.handleRequestClose = this.handleRequestClose.bind(this);
    this.handleTouchTap = this.handleTouchTap.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      open: false,
    };
  }

  handleRequestClose() {
    this.setState({
      open: false,
    });
  }

  handleTouchTap() {
    this.setState({
      open: true,
    });
  }

  render() {
    const standardActions = (
      <FlatButton
        label="Ok"
        primary={true}
        onTouchTap={this.handleRequestClose}
      />
    );

    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiTheme}>
        <div style={styles.container}>
            <Grid>
                <Row>
                    <Col xs={12}>
                        <Row start = "xs">
                            <Col xs = {8}>
                                <LoginDialogComponent />

                            </Col>
                            <Col xs = {2}>
                                <SignUpDialogComponent />
                            </Col>
                            <Col xs = {2} >
                                <LoginDialogComponent label = "Brand" />
                            </Col>

                        </Row>

                    </Col>
                </Row>
                <br></br>
                <Row>   
                  <Col xs={12}>
                    <Row center="xs">
                      <Col xs={12} >
                        <PostList hands = {this.props.hands}/>

                      </Col>
                    </Row>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
            </Grid>

        </div>

      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

Here is PostDetail Component

import React from 'react';

```
export default class PostDetail extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return (<div> Hello World </div>);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not entirely sure what you are asking. Are you saying when you enter a URL in the browser, your component doesn't render? Have you setup a wildcard rule in Express? https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md#configuring-your-server

Comment: When I enter the URL in the browser forbexample www.myurl.com/posts the component doesn't rerender. All I get is test string from express' res.send(test string)

Comment: Well, the `/posts` resource doesn't exist as far as Express is concerned. You need to redirect all requests to your app's entry point so that react router has a chance to kick in. The link I posted should help.

Comment: So in my case to understand it properly, express just always needs to direct all URLs to index.html and react router will kick in from there? If I direct all traffic from server to index.html what do I do about api requests?

Comment: Put your API routes before the wildcard route. But yes, your understanding is correct.

Comment: Okay so now I redirected all the requests to send index.html. However, now react-router only renders the Main Component even on the /posts url and never renders the PostDetail.

Comment: I believe your second route should be nested within your first route.

Comment: It is nested but still not rendering correctly. @Mister Epic'code'<Router history = {browserHistory}>
  <Route path = "/" component = {Main}>
   <Route path = "posts" component = {PostDetail} />
  </Route>
 </Router>